# Solving for $z_{t+1} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2\\ -2& 2 \end{bmatrix}z_{t} - \begin{bmatrix} 24\\ 9 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

The above equation is a nonhomogeneous difference equation. To find the general solution, I have to find the particular solution and a complementary solution.

I have obtained the complementary solution, that is, for the homogeneous difference equation $z_{t+1} = A z_{t}$, which is $$z_{c} = c_{1}\left ( -2 \right )^{n}\begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} + c_{2}\left ( 3 \right )^{n}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

This is after calculating the eigenvalues and the eigenvalues for the matrix $A$.

Now for finding the particular solution, $z_{p}$ I was wondering if I can get some help in guessing a function.

The general solution for the nonhomogeneous difference equation will consist of $z_{n} = z_{c} + z_{p}$.

**EDIT:** For the particular solution, I have solved $z^{*} = A z^{*} + b$ and have solved for vector $$z^{*} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-11
\end{bmatrix} = z_{p}.$$

Thus, for the general solution we have, $$z_{n} =
c_{1}\left ( -2 \right )^{n}\begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} + c_{2}\left ( 3 \right )^{n}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix} +  
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-11
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Does this general solution for the nonhomogeneous difference equation make sense?

Comment: Try guessing that $z_t$ is constant.

Comment: @saulspatz I have made an edit.

Comment: Your solution certainly makes sense.  I haven't checked the actual calculations, though.